# Get random images when clicking on image for javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript, and I was able to create a simple game where the shapes and color will change and it will move around. I am stuck on how to input images...please help me!! =( Thank you! =)

This is the site to the game I created http://sites.codeschool.org.uk/?site=imat3ap0t

I want to change the shapes to 3 jpg pictures I have and have it do the same thing. I am so stuck!

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split(''); //the numbers&letters are for color codes. split is the string (set of numbers and letters into an array)
    var color = '#'; //color codes start with #
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

var clickedTime;
var createdTime;
var reactionTime;

function makeBox() {
    var time = Math.random();
    time = time * 5000;

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius = "100px";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("box").style.borderRadius = "0";
        }

        var top = Math.random();
        top = top * 300;
        var left = Math.random();
        left = left * 500;
        document.getElementById("box").style.top = top + "px";
        document.getElementById("box").style.left = left + "px";
        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
        document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";
        createdTime = Date.now();
    }, time);
}

document.getElementById("box").onclick = function () {
    clickedTime = Date.now();
    reactionTime = (clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = reactionTime;
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
    makeBox();
}

makeBox();
```

Thank you guys for the response!

Comment: Create an array with the names of the pictures and use `Math.randoom()` to select a 'random' picture(speaking in terms of a computer, nothing is really random). Afterwards you have to set the `src` attribute of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Well you will need to modify your function to something like this:

```
function getRandomImage() {
    // All of the image options
    // This is very similar to string of characters you have now
    var images = ['path/to/image/1', 'path/to/image/2', 'path/to/image/3']

    // Randomly select one image path
    // By using images.length we don't have to hardcode the length like the "16" you're using, which is good incase the list changes
    var imagePath =  images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

    // Return random image path
    return imagePath;
}
```

Then you will probably want an `img` tag somewhere in your document, instead of the div you are using now:

```
<img id="changing-image"></img>
```

Then you can use more javascript to find the image and change its `src` property:

```
var image = document.getElementById("changing-image");
image.src = getRandomImage();
```

Comment: He won't learn anything when you just provide the answer. I think it's better to give some hints and let him self find out how it works.

Comment: This is always the fine line to walk I suppose.  I try to add comments that explain what each line is doing, in hopes that OP will learn from the comments.

Comment: Hey Tyler, thank you so much for your help. I used your codes and what I have learned and it worked! GuyT, I know what you mean about not giving the answer. I reallllly tried looking for the answers and it just wasn't working...so I decided to ask for help. I am super new at this and I hope I will learn much more and be able to code without needing too much help.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/qezagay/edit?html,output

This is what I made for my online course. The only thing I have trouble with now is the positioning..so I am working on that now.

@Tyler Thank you!